# Python versions of tutorials

Tags: ros, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In for example, http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom , example is written in C++

1. I assume that just about any ROS program in C++ could be written in Python. True?
2. Is there a general way to find python equivalents to the specific examples used in ROS Tutorials? A catalog or other resource?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280410/python-versions-of-tutorials/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2018-01-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-01-22**:
have you check the book for this ? if no please search Programming Robots with ROS: A Practical Introduction to the Robot Operating system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking further I see that many of the tutorials have parallel steps for C++ and Pythong, displayed side by side in a table. I guess I just missed it. Sorry!

---

Originally posted by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) with karma: 628 on 2018-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0